# Store a vector of pointers to custom objects to file

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

I am using the boost example code to store a vector of pointers of objects in a file.
My vector is:

```
class VOMC{
public:
    vector<State*> vomc;
...
...
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & vomc;
    }
}
```

This gives me the following error(among few more):

```
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:118:9: error: ‘class State’ has no member named ‘serialize’
```

The error makes is probably telling me that I should also make my *State* object serializable(not sure on that one). Furthermore, I am confused because storing the pointers(addresses to memory) does not store the actual data, which will be freed upon program termination. Is there a workaround for the above situation? Even without boost.

Comment: Yes, `State` must be serializable, and actual object will be serialized ("deep" serialization). Please read the manual: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `serialize` method for your `State` class.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

> Each member of the array stops will be serialized. But remember each member is a pointer - so what can this really mean? The whole object of this serialization is to permit reconstruction of the original data structures at another place and time. **In order to accomplish this with a pointer, it is not sufficient to save the value of the pointer, rather the object it points to must be saved. When the member is later loaded, a new object has to be created and a new pointer has to be loaded into the class member**.

Also i think you should read about [serialization of pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#pointeroperators)